# OpenCV resize is not a member of cv (OpenCV Basics)

Tags: c++, opencv

I successfully wrote a tool that converts an image's colors space from linear to sRGB, so opencv is working. Then i wanted to rescale the image with the **cv::resize** function to generate Thumbnails. However it didn't work, here is the reproduced code-snippet.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Load images in the C++ format
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("something.jpg");
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("src.jpg");

    // Resize src so that is has the same size as img
    **cv::resize**(src, src, img.size());

    return 0;
}
```

I am using OpenCV 2.4.8. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you're lacking a header file:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

(ofc, you have to link opencv_imgproc, too)

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

would have avoided the 1st error, but you still have to care for the correct libs

Comment: probably,  [looking at the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/) helps (thy're ordered by modules, and there's 1 header per module)

Comment: I already had the libs and dlls added correctly, i think i was including "opencv2/opencv.hpp" before. That why i had never problems with includes.

Comment: Afaik #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" is all you need for amy non-nonfree module include